# How to read data from a text file then writing them in an Excel file using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on code were I read data from an existed text file, then I'm trying to write it inside an Excel file by creating a new one.

```
distance_matrix.txt
```

> [0]
>
> [1, 0]
>
> [13, 12, 0]
>
> [17, 16, 10, 0]
>
> [16, 15, 8, 1, 0]
>
> [13, 12, 4, 5, 4, 0]
>
> [12, 11, 6, 11, 10, 6, 0]

- I first opened the text file then read it and stored it in a list.

  `file1 = open("distance_matrix.txt", "r")
  contents1 = file1.readlines()`
- Then I have stored ***contents1*** in another list (I'm not sure if it's really a list because when I print it I only get the last line!).

```
    import re
    numbers = []
    for i in contents1:
            numbers = re.split(', |\[|\]', i)
            numbers.remove('')
            numbers.remove('\n')

    for i in numbers:
        print(numbers[0])
```

- After that, I'm trying to write it to an Excel file by first creating a new one then writing.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {#"A":numbers}
    )

    writer = ExcelWriter("MyData.xls")
    df.to_excel(writer,"sheet1", index = False)
    writer.save()
```

> My question is how would I write this triangle shape inside the Excel file with a header to each column after taking those numbers from the text file?
>
> A  B  C  D  E  F  G
>
> [0]
>
> [1, 0]
>
> [13, 12, 0]
>
> [17, 16, 10, 0]
>
> [16, 15, 8, 1, 0]
>
> [13, 12, 4, 5, 4, 0]
>
> [12, 11, 6, 11, 10, 6, 0]

Answer (score 1):

by default the headers are `True`,

`DataFrame.to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None, header=True, index=True, index_label=None, startrow=0, startcol=0, engine=None, merge_cells=True, encoding=None, inf_rep='inf', verbose=True, freeze_panes=None)`,

Try adding `header=False`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {#"A":numbers}
    )

    writer = ExcelWriter("MyData.xls")
    df.to_excel(writer,"sheet1", index = False, header=False)
    writer.save()
```